# Why does the Tycho-2 catalog not include Hipparcos stars?

Tags: star

Both use the same data. But at least, 90k stars are lost in Tycho-2. 
Why?

Comment: Could you provide a specific example?

Comment: @barrycarter There are 90k Hippacos sources in tgas catalog released by Gaia recently.

Comment: http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/all/tycho2.html lists 2 supplements to Tycho 2 ("overly bright" stars) and I count ~18734 stars there.

Comment: @barrycarter  The question is 93k >> 18374.

Comment: Please clarify your question and what catalogues or sources you are looking at.

Answer (score 3):

Could you give a source or example: The Tycho-II catalogue paper by [Hog et al. (2000)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000A&A...355L..27H) suggests there are about 19,000 stars in Hipparcos or Tycho-I that are not in Tycho-II. This can be because they are too bright (but that is not very many stars) or for other reasons that are not clearly specified (binarity is an issue I think).

Looking at [this website](http://www.astro.ku.dk/~erik/Tycho-2/faq.html), it suggests 4% of stars did not have proper motions and could not be assigned epoch 2000 positions in Tycho II but I don't think these are *missing*.